# Initial an array with an object default value in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

I have following classes and I would like to initialize citiesRegistered with initial values of city object which contains parks 'Times' and 'Blues' and schools as 'High' and middle but currently it is an empty object

```
export const initialState: CustomerState = {
  customer: new Customer(),
};

export class Customer{
id: number;
age: number;
cars: carClass;
phoneNumbers: string[];
}

export class carClass{
name:string;
citiesRegistered:city[] = [];   //This is what makes it empty. How can I put default values of cities in here
}

export class city{
parks: string[] = ['Times','Blues'],
lakes: string[] = [],
schools: string[] = ['High','Middle']
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may need to change the initialization and default values a bit:

```
class Car {
    name: string = '';
    citiesRegistered: City = {
        lakes: ['MyLake'],
        parks: ['MyPark'],
        schools: ['MySchool']
    }
}

class Customer {
    id: number = 0;
    age: number = 0;
    car: Car = new Car();
    phoneNumbers: string[] = [];
}

const initialState = {
    customer: new Customer(),
};


class City {
    parks: string[] = ['Times', 'Blues']
    lakes: string[] = []
    schools: string[] = ['High', 'Middle']
}

console.log(initialState.customer.car.citiesRegistered)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
lakes: ["MyLake"]
parks: ["MyPark"]
schools: ["MySchool"]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYCdoG8BQ0PQHZgLYFMAuaCAFwQEssBzaAXmgHJGBudTYC0i-CAJXzUKZfAnwATYrC4BPeinaZM4ANa9iAbUYBZGQBkwaxgF0ANIqXQADohURNOmQAVbJ85cwRgACwD2vkHtoLV0AZR9-EBMLAF9UONRQSBhYAFcyXwIkNCUKSWxU3AAjUXkABjYlMGoiAuLShgqLYEQpRHksfAB3OEQACgBKSswrP06AOUKShCCyShoNY3lFtgTgXywyaCouCjAQUNIwUnx5HI500kzRYk6etIyswfMYtlRE8Cg4WQUlGwQ7MQ5lRqItlowACoUAgQRimJgAIRAqV40SUqnUJHIILBDEWFi8fgCs2xCyWeMYAAkKNRvHCmNo8uIQPhomsNhAAvgAHQgXzUPo7bj7Q7HHnAS7XBDclrSzjcXgCIQiMTiAZAA)